# How to write multiple column "in" sql query syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write multiple column "in" sql query syntax?

Example :-

I am looking for the name : Peter in all of these 3 columns (or) any of these 3 columns : colA, colB, colC from the table : TableA

```
select * from TableA
where (colA, colB, colC) in 'Peter'
```

Table has the columns in a Pivot format. Alternate would be .. writing a union query for each column in syntax.

Comment: why not using OR... i.e. colA in 'Peter' OR colB in 'Peter' OR colC in 'Peter' ....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the cardinality of the dataset, values in those columns equal to "Peter", the effects could be similar or different for the following two scenarios:

```
select * from TableA
where colA = 'Peter' OR colB = 'Peter' OR colC = 'Peter'
```

and

```
select *
from TableA
where colA = 'Peter'

union

select *
from TableA
where colB = 'Peter'

union

select *
from TableA
where colC = 'Peter'
```

However, my recommendation would be to use the UNION version since it might give better performance in scenarios where the cardinality of "Peter" in each column is small.

Comment: My existing query has union on it . i am working on replacing the lengthy syntax

Comment: @goofyui In my opinion you're trying to solve a nonproblem. However, I'm glad you found your answer and in the meantime I've found out something new. +1 for Ryan

Comment: @Radhu, I am with you. +1 for Ryan :)

Comment: Ryan's syntax is breaking when we pass more than one name. In the real time scenario, this will become as a Subquery for IN. I will have to use OR syntax.

Answer (score 9):

Can you try

```
select * from TableA
where 'Peter' in (colA, colB, colC)
```

Comment: I am testing this result in real time.. I will accept in few mins

Comment: This is a valid syntax, at least in SQL Server. To the optimiser it is equivalent to `'Peter' = colA OR 'Peter' = colB OR 'Peter' = colC`

Comment: @VladimirBaranov , Thanks .. I am with you in this syntax. It is valid

Comment: This is a valid syntax in SQL Server, MySql, Postgresql. I'm sure :)

Comment: @RyanNghiem ... sorry this syntax is breaking .. when we try to pass more than one name , it becomes as Sub Query for IN. This query will work only if we have one value to it

Comment: @goofyui if u want more than one value, u should write into the question. I'll edit my answer correct. So easy for my way :)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, this is ideal since you are looking for a single name

```
select * from TableA
where colA='Peter' OR colB='Peter'OR colC='Peter'
```